# How to check is the current session is persistent or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

When i am doing user LogOn i need to set IsPersistent parameter

```
SignInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent, false);
```

On my site i have functionality of changing UserName of current user. If UserName has changed my current coockies make not actual, so i need to LogOut user and then to login, but i dont know is user checked remmember me or not.
How can i in my site know is session isPersistent or not?
Or is there any other way to handle changing UserName not desinchron with coockies?

**UPDATE:**

I use

```
_user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

in my Base Controller to track current User.
Asp.Net Identity has property `User.Identity.Name` but not `User.Identity.Id`, and this name stored somewhere in coockies. Is there any way to change system to track not names but ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every user should have some sort of user id. If you are storing the users in a database they will already have one. If you want you can also add a custom generated id to every user when they are created.

Then you can use that user id to associate the user with their cookies. This id will be unique to the user and will not change when the user name changes. Using this approach will avoid your problem altogether.

**Update**

You can get the user id from the identity like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;    

int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

I would need to see how you are creating cookies in order to help you further with that.

Comment: I updated post. The Asp.Net Identity tracks Names itself. I want system to track ids but i dont know how.

Comment: Difficult choice what answer to make mark as answer. Answer of  Gaurav P first helps to solve problem, but your answer with update is more complex, so i mark it. Thanks.